# sublimecodeintel doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimecodeintel

I tried everything to make it work.but I was failed.
here is the .codeintel/codeintel.log:
`{
    “PHP”：{
        “php”：'/ usr / bin / php'
        “phpExtraPaths”：[]
        “phpConfigFile”：'php.ini'
    }，
    “JavaScript”：{
        “javascriptExtraPaths”：[]
    }，
    “Perl”：{
        “perl”：“/ usr / bin / perl”，
        “perlExtraPaths”：[]
    }，
    “Ruby”：{
        “ruby”：“/ usr / bin / ruby​​”，
        “rubyExtraPaths”：[]
    }，
    “Python”：{
        “python”：'/ usr / bin / python'
        “pythonExtraPaths”：['/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
    }，
    “Python3”：{
        “python”：'/ usr / bin / python3'
        “pythonExtraPaths”：[]
    }
}`

I used the SublimeText 3 with OSX 10.12.4
Did I should find the pythonExtraPaths ? But I don't know how to do it.

Can you help me?please.